# Hi,It may be a same issue on spring Autowiring,but still i cannot find a solution

Tags: spring, autowired, managed-bean, spring-annotations

I'm trying to create basic CRUD operations using JSF 2.2, Spring 4.01, and Hibernate. From register.xhtml, if I click the register button, then it should save `firstname` (as of now) in the database.

I have the following:

1. A registration page (`register.xhtml`)
2. `RegistrationAction` (the controller)
3. `RegistrationEntity` (an entity class which has only one field, `firstName`, as of now)
4. `LoginRegistrationServiceImpl` (a service class) -- This implements the interface `LoginRegistrationService`

When deploying, I get this exception:

```
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Cant instantiate class: Controllers.RegistrationAction.
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Injection of autowired dependencies failed for class [class Controllers.RegistrationAction]
```

I tried the below changes.

1. `<context:component-scan base-package />`
2. I separately created like this: `<bean id="lrInterface" class="Serviceimplementations.LoginRegistrationSerImpl"/>`
3. I used `@Configuration` and `@ComponentScan("Serviceimplementations")` instead of declaring in configuration file.
4. Initially I used `@ManagedBean` and `@Controller` in `RegistrationAction`. After that, I changed to `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport`.

Note: I don't have a parameterized constructor. I searched many relevant topics, and this may be a silly error, but I still don't know how to solve it.

RegistrationAction.java:

```java
@ManagedBean(name="register")
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("Serviceimplementations")
public class RegistrationAction extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport implements Serializable {    
    private LoginRegistrationSerImpl lrInterfcae;
    public LoginRegistrationSerImpl getLrInterfcae() {
        return lrInterfcae;
    }
    @Autowired
    public void setLrInterfcae(LoginRegistrationSerImpl lrInterfcae) {             
        this.lrInterfcae = lrInterfcae;
        System.out.println("Interface Obj--" + lrInterfcae);
    }
}
```

LoginRegistrationImpl.java:

```java
@Service("lrInterfcae")
public class LoginRegistrationSerImpl implements LoginRegistrationService{
    @Override
    public void saveUser(RegistrationEntity reg) {
        System.out.println("impl");       
    }
}
```

Register.xhtml:

```html
    <...
        <h:commandButton value="REGISTER" id="register" action="#{register.registerUser()}" /> 
    ...>
```

Output:

```
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Cant instantiate class: Controllers.RegistrationAction.
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:191)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:257)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:80)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:135)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:174)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getValue(UIInput.java:291)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Injection of autowired dependencies failed for class [class Controllers.RegistrationAction]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void Controllers.RegistrationAction.setLrInterfcae(Serviceimplementations.LoginRegistrationSerImpl); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [Serviceimplementations.LoginRegistrationSerImpl] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.processInjection(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:310)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.<init>(SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.java:68)
    at Controllers.RegistrationAction.<init>(RegistrationAction.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:186)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void Controllers.RegistrationAction.setLrInterfcae(Serviceimplementations.LoginRegistrationSerImpl); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [Serviceimplementations.LoginRegistrationSerImpl] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.processInjection(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:307)
    ... 68 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [Serviceimplementations.LoginRegistrationSerImpl] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1100)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:553)
    ... 70 more
```

Comment: How to align the output segment in the above question?